# Show the operator is self-adjoint on a period function

Tags: linear-algebra, self-adjoint-operators

Let $V$ be a vector space of all $2\pi$-periodic function from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb C$ with the inner product:

$$\langle f,g \rangle =\int_0^{2\pi} \overline{f(x)}g(x)dx$$

$$A:V\to V, f\to \frac{df}{dx}$$

Now, my attempt

$$\langle Af,g \rangle =\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\overline{f(x)}}{dx}g(x)dx=\overline{f(x)}g(x) \biggr |^{2\pi}_0-\int_0^{2\pi} \overline{f(x)}\frac{g(x)}{dx}dx$$

And here i'm stuck. This is supposed to equal to $\langle f,Ag\rangle$ to complete the answer right?

and second part:

Let $$U=\text{span}\{x \rightarrow e^{inx}=\sin(nx)+i \cos(nx) \mid n\in \Bbb Z\}$$

be the induced inner product. Find a orthonormal basis of U and the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $A_{|U}$.

I don't quite understand what the second part wants me to do, appreciate any help!

Comment: What does the periodicity of $f$ and $g$ tell you about the boundary term?

Comment: I don't actually know what the boundary term is....

Comment: $f(0)=f(2 \pi)$ and $g(0)=g(2 \pi)$

Comment: @Fred is it defined to be 0? ouhh didnt know that. But that would leave me with $<Af,g>=-<f,Ag>$ would that still satisfy the condition for A to be self adjoint?

Comment: Shouldn't it be $\frac{d f(x)}{d x}$ instead of $\frac{f(x)}{d x}$? For $A$ to be self-adjoint, you indeed need $\langle A f, g \rangle = \langle f, A g \rangle$.

Comment: You appear to be checking that the operator is symmetric, it's unfortunately possible that your course does not distinguish between these two concepts though.

Comment: Unless I’m crazy, they’re not actually symmetric. Take $\langle A\sin x,\cos x\rangle=\pi,\langle\sin x,A\cos x\rangle=-\pi$